# How do I reflect a known density in a Poisson distribution?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I saw this [great video series from Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability/random-variables-stats-library/poisson-distribution/v/poisson-process-1) about the Poisson distribution. The video derives the Poisson distribution equation by using an example of counting the number of cars that pass by.

The equation for the [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) is:

$P(k $ events in interval$) = \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$

And $\lambda$ seems to only be dependent on the *rate* of observation: if I'm watching cars pass by on the road and I see a car going down the street once a minute, then the probability of seeing a car going down the street is just $1^1 e^{-1}/1! = 36.79\%$.

But now let's say that I know that the street I'm observing happens to be an on-ramp to a major highway. $\lambda$ then really becomes dependent on the time of day I'm observing the street. There's going to be a lot less traffic passing on that road at 3am than at 7am, for instance. It seems that if I include more information about this road, then my probability will change (and get better).

So I'm thinking - can we find some sort of $\lambda^*$ that reflects this fact?

- What if $\lambda^* = \lambda(t)$? This now requires that I make observations for all times in the day, and my probability explicitly requires knowing the time of day. Not bad, but I'd like one equation
- What if $\lambda^* = \bar{\lambda}?$ I still have to make observations at each time of the day, and then take an average. Problem is, if this on-ramp is only heavily used during rush hour then an average will unfairly skew $\lambda^*$ lower.
- What if I weigh $\lambda^*$ by knowing how much traffic *could* have taken the on-ramp? For instance, if I both observe the number of cars that are in the right lane (for this example, consider that this lane lets you turn right OR go straight), then I could weigh each measurement - how many cars actually took the on-ramp divided by the total number of cars that could have, hour-by-hour.

Is there a good way to include that information into the Poisson distribution equation?

Comment: The treatment of Poisson processes with variable arrival rate $\lambda(t)$ is quite standard, but of course it is assumed that $\lambda(t)$ is a known function. But you not only want $\lambda(t)$ to be a function that needs to be estimated, you even refuse to assume that the value of $t$ is known. So, what meaning do you assign to the estimate that $\lambda(t)$ has value $5$, say, for some unknown value of time instant $t$, and has estimated value $3.9$, say, at   some other unknown time instant $t^\prime$ ??

Comment: Not that I don't want to acknowledge $t$, but for the model I'm considering I'm hoping for a "first cut" that is independent of time. If the resulting probability does not meet requirements then I can refine the model by explicitly knowing $t$.